# How can I verify all the messages in a source topic are replicated to a target (remote) topic in Kafka using MirrorMaker2

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

Looking for a simplw way to verify all messages in a source topic are replicated to a remote topic using MM2, specifically topics receiving high throughput/volume.

Here's my simple deployment,

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: KafkaMirrorMaker2
metadata:
    name: my-mirror-maker-2
spec:
    version: 3.4.0
    connectCluster: "target-dev"
    replicas: 3
    clusters:
    - alias: "dev"
      bootstrapServers: dev:9094
    - alias: "target-dev"
      bootstrapServers: target-dev:9094
      # config:
      #    offset-syncs.topic.max.compaction.lag.ms: 120000
    mirrors:
    - sourceCluster: "dev"
      targetCluster: "target-dev"
      sourceConnector:
        tasksMax: 9
        config:
          replication.factor: 3
      heartbeatConnector: {}
      checkpointConnector: {}
```

I realize mirrormaker2-cluster-offsets will have a key containing the source topic metadata and the value will have the latest offset from the source, so its a compacted topic. But it's hard to verify/filter out from the provectus/kafka-ui I'm using.

Wanted to know if anyone has discovered a more efficient way. Thanks.

Comment: Counting offsets from a compacted topic won't prove anything. Especially if the mirroring is always reading from non-compacted segments

Comment: `@OneCricketeer` then how do one verify data is getting replicating properly